# Capturing keypress and passing a value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, events

i have this on a template in my laravel application

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment" onkeyup="handleEvt(this, {{$post->id}}, e)"/>
```

and i want a user to be able to post a comment by just hitting the enter key, after typing. i have the `handleEvt()` function with three params.

the first parameter - this, is used to get the input object using jquery `$(this)`
and the second parameter - `{{$post->id}}` is for the posts id, and the last parameter (e) is used to capture the event from the keyboard.

this is the equilvalent function in my footer

```
function handleEvt(obj, pid, e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //where 13 is the enter button
      v = $(obj).val();
      alert('it is working');
    }
}
```

i try to run this code, but i'm not getting any alert, that is, the code is not working as expected, please can someone help me out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global event object is called `event`, not `e`. Correct HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment" 
       onkeyup="handleEvt(this, {{$post->id}}, event)" />
```

Or it can be even simpler without redundant `this` reference `onkeyup="handleEvt(event, {{$post->id}})"`:

```
function handleEvt(e, pid) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // where 13 is the enter button
      var v = e.target.value;
      alert('it is working:' + v);
    }
}
```

Comment: noted, and thanks for the correction. i have sorted it out... its working now

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out

```
 <input name="myComment" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment" />
```

and In javascript try this

```
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var comment = $('input[name=myComment]').val();
       if(e.which == 13 && comment !='') {
          alert('clicked');
       }
 });
```

Comment: hmmm, i'm doubting if this would work on all browsers accurately..  rather than using this, why not stick to using the ID selector, kinda prefer that... or what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

use the event property and use it as a first paramater like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment" onkeyup="handleEvt(event,this, 1)"/>
```

```js
function handleEvt(e,obj, pid){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //where 13 is the enter button
      v = $(obj).val();
      alert('it is working');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment" onkeyup="handleEvt(event,this, 1)"/>
```

Comment: thanks much, it worked, learnt something new today, really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

try using `e.which`. You should check `e.keyCode` or `e.which` depending on browser support.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_which.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp

Comment: did it work out for you or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have jquery installed, I would recommend using jQuery to bind the events. This will help with separation of concerns, and you won't need to worry about escaping your parameters. If you do it like this:

```js
function handleEvt(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //where 13 is the enter button
      v = $(this).val()
      alert('it is working');
    }
}

$(function(){
  $('input').on('keyup', handleEvt)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment"/>
```

It will work correctly. `this` is bound to the element that triggered the event.

Comment: if (this) is bound to the element triggered, then how to you get a reference to the post that where the event was fired, since there would be several posts from different users displayed there, note that i was using the {{post->id}}, how would you achieve this in your own case...

Comment: you can add it as a data attribute:
`<input type="text" data-post-id="{{post->id}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Post a comment"/>` which you can then access via jquery. It will also make it marginally easier to access if you want to do other things (sort by post id for instance)